# Formulario en laravel con ajax no envía ficheros

Tags: laravel, ajax

Os comento un problema que me ha surgido.

Estoy realizando un proyecto en [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) donde he creado un formulario en el cual tengo la intención de enviar varias fotos.
El problema se me presenta cuando quiero realizar esto con [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax). El controlador recibe todos los datos del formulario pero no recibe nada de archivos.

Os muestro un poco lo que he intentado.

> El formulario es el siguiente(os dejo algunos campos ya que es muy extenso):

```
{!! Form::open(array("role" => "form", "files" => true, "data-toggle" => "validator", "enctype" => "multipart/form-data")) !!}
            <div class="card ">
                <div class="card-body ">
                    <h4 class="card-title">{{__('form.general')}}</h4>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">{{__('form.nameapartment')}}</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {{Form::text('name', '',['placeholder' => __('form.placeholdername'), 'class' => 'form-control','required'])}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                        
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="fileinput fileinput-new text-center rounded-circle" data-provides="fileinput">
                                        <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail"></div>
                                        <div>
                    <span class="btn btn-rose btn-round btn-file">
                      <span class="fileinput-new">{{__('form.imageapartment')}}</span>

                        <input type="file" name="photos[]" required multiple/>
                    </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer ">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" style="width: 100%">{{__('form.submit')}}</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
```

> Las rutas donde se carga el formulario y la que atiende a la petición ajax son las siguientes:

```
Route::prefix('dashboard')->group(function(){ 
Route::prefix('apartment')->group(function() {
    Route::get('create','dashboard\ApartmentController@create')->name('apartment.createapartment');
    Route::post('store','dashboard\ApartmentController@store')->name('apartment.storeapartment');     
 });
});
```

> El primer script que tenía hecho es el siguiente:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        var form = $('form');

        form.submit(function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url     : 'dashboard/apartment/store',
                type    : 'POST',
                data    : form.serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',                    
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            }).done(

                function(data)
                {
                    $('#ajaxviews').html(data.html);
                }
            );
        });

    });
```

> Con este primer script los archivos no llegaban a subirse, al realizar un `dd($request->all())` no aparece el input con las fotos.
>   Después de indagar un poco por Internet  he visto que se necesita crear un objeto de `FormData` para poder enviar archivos. **Por lo tanto, ahora mismo tengo este script**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var form = new FormData($('form'));


        form.submit(function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url     : 'dashboard/apartment/store',
                type    : 'POST',
                data    : form,
                dataType: 'json',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            }).done(

                function(data)
                {
                    $('#ajaxviews').html(data.html);
                }
            );
        });

    });
```

Ahora se añade otro problema, cuando le doy a enviar al formulario me está volviendo a cargar la ruta de "create" (no llega al controlador) dándome un error ya que la llamada a dicha ruta es por `GET` y se está realizando por `POST`:

[image: Error que da al enviar el formulario]

Entiendo que los ficheros, si se están subiendo ahora pero como no llego al controlador no puedo confirmarlo:

[image: Si recibe los datos]

¿Como puedo solucionar esto? Dado que esto es para un proyecto de clase todavía se me escapan muchos conceptos que pueden faltarme para realizar esto.

Saludos y gracias!

Comment: En que parte del form estas declarando el method?

Comment: El method lo estoy especificando en la parte del script donde se especifica la petición ajax con `type    : 'POST'`

Comment: El tema es que, si especifico el `method` me hace lo mismo y entiendo que no es obligatorio al 100% ya que sin especificarlo la petición `ajax` funciona (aunque los ficheros no llegan) con el formulario, llegando los datos al controlador y pudiendo validarlos (después de validar correctamente o no se me vuelve a cargar la vista correctamente). Si especifico el `method` y el `action` en el form me lo realiza todo correctamente (incluso llegan los ficheros) pero me devuelve la vista con el `html` en plano y entiendo en esta situación que la solicitud no se esté haciendo por `ajax`??